# How can I make a Warforged large?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, creature-size, warforged

Because of my inexperience, I made a Warforged tripper, and expected the party wizard to cast Enlarge Person on me when battles were predicted.
He is perfectly willing, but we just realized a Construct (Living Construct) is not a valid target for Enlarge Person.

What low level options (spells or magic items generally available at level 6) are there to increase my size without giving up my general shape and form? I still want to be able to cast spells and handle my guisarme.

The goal would be 3 times per day, one minute each.

Potential spellcasters: Bard 5, Wizard 5, Cleric 3 (me).

Comment: Related: [How can a magical beast's size be increased using spells or magic items?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94682/how-can-a-magical-beasts-size-be-increased-using-spells-or-magic-items/94699#94699)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably turn to [researching a spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/arcaneSpells.htm). See if the dm will ok an "enlarge construct" or other spell as specific as "enlarge person" at the same spell level for the wizard to research. Don't try to just make a better enlarge person - mimic its limitations, but tailor it to fit your needs within those limitations.

Comment: [Related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3515/8610)

Comment: *"This isn't even my final form"*. Id also go with researching a new spell to let constructs morph into a bigger form.

Answer (score 4):

In a campaign with psionics, the best low-level size increase is attained from a **[*psionic tattoo*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicItemsCCDT.html#psionic-tattoo) of [expansion](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersDtoF.html#expansion)** (*XPH* 105-6) (1st-level power at manifester level 3) (150 gp; 0 lbs.), with the *psionic tattoo*'s creator picking to augment the power so as to increase its duration to 30 min. (It's even possible for a GM to rule—because a [psionic tattoo's activation](http://dndsrd.net/psionicItemsCCDT.html#psionic-tattoo-activation) only requires the possessor to touch the tattoo and will its effect into being—that a raging barbarian can activate a psionic tattoo's effects! Something to consider as barbarianing and tripping go together well.)

In a campaign without psionics, this is far more difficult. The ***belt of growth*** (*Magic Item Compendium* 73-4) (3,000 gp; 0 lbs.) *should* work on any wearer… except that upon activation the wearer "instantly increase in size (as if affected by [*enlarge person*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#enlarge-person))." This DM doesn't have a problem with that parenthetical *as if* meaning here that *the specifics of this item changes the general rules* so that this *enlarge person* effect works on a wolf wearer or a mind flayer wearer as well as it works on a humanoid wearer, but your DM's view may vary.

Beyond that, a warforged is left with higher-level or more expensive means that may not fly well with the DM; these can be viewed in answers to this similar question about increasing the size of a magical beast [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94682/8610).

Answer (score 1):

It’s several levels away, but eventually you will be able to cast the *righteous might* cleric spell, which increases your size as well as several other buffs. It’s overpriced (for a 5th-level spell, it should either be faster to cast or last longer—it isn’t really worth burning a turn on at 9th level or higher, but since it lasts about a minute, it may be difficult to have it already up and running when combat happens), but it has no concerns about your type.